# Game won't reset iOS

Tags: ios

Hi I am in the early stages of making my first 'collision' game in Xcode.

I have written this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pos = CGPointMake(5.0,4.0);
}

- (IBAction)start {
    [startbutton setHidden:YES];
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.03) target:(self) selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)onTimer {

    [self checkCollision];

    enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos.x,enemy.center.y+pos.y);

    if (enemy.center.x > 320 || enemy.center.x <0)
        pos.x= -pos.x;
    if (enemy.center.y > 480 || enemy.center.y < 0)
        pos.y = -pos.y;
}

-(void)checkCollision {
    if( CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,enemy.frame))
    {
        [randomMain invalidate];
        [startbutton setHidden:NO];

        pos = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

        CGRect frame = [player frame];
        frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
        frame.origin.y = 326.0;
        [player setFrame:frame];

        CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
        frame2.origin.x = 137.0f;
        frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
        [enemy setFrame:frame2];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lost!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You were hit! Try Again!"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Though when I run it in the simulator and the 'enemy' and 'player' collide, and the user presses 'Try again' the game does not reset. Can anyone tell me what code is missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show the code executed when the user presses 'Try again'

Comment: @bobnoble no code comes into the output when playing or when theres a collision

Comment: When collision occurs, `pos` is set to `CGPointZero` which would cause `enemy.center` to stop changing in `onTimer`. Is that what you mean by "the game does not reset"?

Comment: @bobnoble - I guess so, It runs perfectly the first time, though when the user collides with the enemy and you click try again the enemy doesn't move. Do I need to change those values you mentioned?

Comment: Suggest returning a `BOOL` from the `checkCollision` method to indicate whether a collision occurred, and if so, don't update the `enemy` position, and don't set `pos` to `CGPointZero`. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -(void)onTimer {
>
> ```
> if (![self checkCollision]){
>
>     enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos.x,enemy.center.y+pos.y);
>
>     if (enemy.center.x > 320 || enemy.center.x <0)
>         pos.x= -pos.x;
>     if (enemy.center.y > 480 || enemy.center.y < 0)
>         pos.y = -pos.y; 
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>
> -(BOOL)checkCollision {
>
> ```
> if( CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,enemy.frame))
> {
>     [randomMain invalidate];
>     [startbutton setHidden:NO];
>
>     CGRect frame = [player frame];
>     frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
>     frame.origin.y = 326.0;
>     [player setFrame:frame];
>
>     CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
>     frame2.origin.x = 137.0f;
>     frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
>     [enemy setFrame:frame2];
>
>     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lost!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You were hit! Try Again!"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
>     [alert show];
>
>     return YES;
>     }
>
>    return NO;
> ```
>
> }